# Trying to install trity and it gives me the error

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install trity and after install it any time I want to run it gives me the error

The error is:

```
sh: 1: route: not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/trity/trity.py", line 27, in <module>
    from searchs import *
  File "/opt/trity/searchs.py", line 1, in <module>
    from google import search
ImportError: No module named google
```

Answer (score 0):

try to install google.

```
pip install search_google
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

In the directory /Trity-1/trity/ and edit searchs.py

Clear the first line by putting:

```
from googlesearch import search
```

Then go back to the root of the directory /Trity-1/ edit a text file by naming it, and save.

```
touch agree.txt
```

Now you can start trity doing

```
python trity.py
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and consider editing your answer

Answer (score 0):

How I solved the problem.

Go to your Trity-1 directory
run `sudo python2 uninstall.py`

1. `xdg-open install.py`
2. everywhere you see something like os.system('pip install SOMETHING') , you should replace `pip` with `pip2.7`.
3. also add line `os.system('pip2.7 install search_google')`
4. Save and close
5. `sudo python2 install.py`

Hope I helped

Answer (score 0):

**First uninstall trity to start afresh**

For non-root:

> Sudo python uninstall.py

**Then follow my lead**

First, make changes on install.py

change the lines as follow or you can copy and paste to a code editor

On operating system section option

```
option = raw_input("\033[0m[>] Select Operating System: \033[0m")

    if option == "1":
        print "\033[1;33m[*] Loading...\033[0m"
        os.system('apt-get install python-pip')
        os.system('easy_install pip')
        import pip

        os.system('sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev libfreetype6 zlib1g-dev')
        os.system('pip install --upgrade beautifulsoup4')
        os.system('pip install search_google')
        os.system('pip install requests')
        os.system('pip install pythonwhois')
        os.system('pip install --upgrade html5lib')
        os.system('pip install pillow')
        os.system('pip install qrcode')
        os.system('pip install requests[security]')
        os.system('pip install http://effbot.org/downloads/Imaging-1.1.6.tar.gz')
        install = os.system("apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential git")
        install2 = os.system("cp -R trity/ /opt/ && cp trity.py /opt/trity && cp run.sh /opt/trity && cp run.sh /usr/bin/trity && chmod +x /usr/bin/trity")
        os.system('apt-get install sendemail')
        os.system('apt-get install libncurses5')
        from pip._internal import main
        main(["install", "scapy", "pythonwhois", "BeautifulSoup", "requests", "mechanize", "google", "qrcode"])
        print "\033[1;32m[!] Finished Installing! Run 'trity' to run program [!]\033[0m"
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print "Whoops! Something went wrong!"
```

**Secondly, Save install.py**

**Then on trity/searchs.py, change the following lines or copy and paste**

```
from googlesearch import search
class color:
   OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
   WARNING = '\033[93m'
   FAIL = '\033[91m'
   UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
   END = '\033[0m'
   ENDC = '\033[0m'
W  = '\033[0m'  # white (normal)
R  = '\033[31m' # red
G  = '\033[32m' # green
O  = '\033[33m' # orange
B  = '\033[34m' # blue
P  = '\033[35m' # purple
C  = '\033[36m' # cyan
T  = '\033[93m' # tan
M = '\033[1;35;32m' # magenta
def googleSearch():
    lol = raw_input(color.UNDERLINE + ""+T+"Query>" + color.END)
    for url in search(lol, tld='com', lang='es', stop=50):
        print(""+G+"Site: "+W+"" + url)
```

Then save, trity/searchs.py

On trity.py change the single line

** import google

To    `import googlesearch`

Then save, trity.py

Done

So run

> sudo python install.py

Thanks, Karibu tena

Answer (score 0):

but except for solutions above (wich you have to use anyway), I have solution for you for 2020-10.

First (Ubuntu 18.04), ubuntu does not longer use eth0 name for network.

So here (after install)

"trity/info.py:mac_address = os.popen("cat /sys/class/net/eth0/address").read()"

You have to change eth0 to enp2s0

Another big problem was that (I am talking about email function), program add @gmail to every victim email. So If you want to try your email (as a victim) on yahoo you were out of luck.

Solution is (again after install) to edit smtp.py line 29 where you change

"attack = '@gmail.com'"

to (Clearly moderator who completely redline all my effort doesnt know about testing purposes or doesnt realize that I am talking about code, not the attack, thx for throwing all my work away)

"attack = ''" /////// eh basicly drop @gmail, leave single quotes

It took me about 5 hours to find out everything, so I hope it will help somebody